# Access Route values in ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

My `route` is defined as `http:/.../home/index/1` which is  `(controller/action/id)`.

ViewModel is as below..

```
   public class TestVM
   {
       [CustomValidation]
       public string name{get; set;}
   }

   public class CustomValidation : ValidationAttribute
   {
       protected override ValidationResult? IsValid (object? value, validationContext)
       {   
         var vm = (TestVM)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
         //how to get the route value here?
       }
   }
```

To validate `Name` property, I need to have value of `Id`. To access `route value` in the `IsValid` method, I defined one more property `Id` in the `TestVM`.
Is there a way to access the `Id` in the `IsValid` without defining in the `TestVM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to access the Id in the IsValid without defining in the
> TestVM?

Seems you are trying to access parameter which has been passed to controller route so that, you can get those values inside your `CustomValidation class`

Well, using `IHttpContextAccessor` we can get all route value from which are available within `HttpContext.Request`. Thus, you can access property `name` of member of `TestVM class`.

**Access Route Value Inside ValidationAttribute:**

You can implement in following way:

```cs
public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var vm = context.ObjectInstance as TestVM;

            var httpContextAccessor = context.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()

            var getIdFromRouteValue = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["Id"];
            var getNameFromRouteValue = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["name"];

            vm.Id = getIdFromRouteValue;
            vm.name = getNameFromRouteValue;
            return ValidationResult.Success;


        }
    }
```

**Program.cs:**

`IHttpContextAccessor` requires to register `AddHttpContextAccessor()` service on your `program.cs` file. You can do as following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

**Note:** Please make sure you have followed the correct order. [You can get more details on our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components)

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `(IHttpContextAccessor)context.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor))` - but why? There is generic version of the method - `context.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()`. Or possibly even better - `context.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()`.

Comment: Yes, this can also be done, my intension was to demonstrate how can we implement that. Thanks for your response and I have updated my answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot!! But I had to use `...Request.RouteValues..` to get the values. For some reason the `...Query..` was not returning anything